# Taking Square Root of Modulo $a$ when $a = p^2$ and $p$ is a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Normally when taking square root of $x$ modulo $a$, $a = p*q$, where $p$ and $q$ are primes, you would compute $$\sqrt{x} \pmod p$$ $$\sqrt{x} \pmod q$$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to compute $$\sqrt{x} \pmod {pq}$$

This method would work for example when $a = 143$, and $p=13, q = 11$. However, what approach would I use when $a = 121$? $p=q=11$, and I won't be able to use CRT because $\sqrt{x} \pmod p == \sqrt{x} \pmod q$. I could probably do it by hand, but is there a better approach that doesn't involves that?

Comment: See [Hensel lifting,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_Lifting) a generalization of Newton's method. For literature see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/709564/242)

Comment: So in my example $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $p = 121$?

Comment: For $\,\sqrt d\,$ use $f(x) = x^2 -d\ $ and $\ p = 11.\ $ If you search on "Hensel" you can find worked examples in prior answers.