# Looking for this article by Paulo Ribenboim

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

While going through a forum post (http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=40112), I found the following paper mentioned:

---

87a:12014 12J10 13A18
Ribenboim, Paulo (3-QEN)
Equivalent forms of Hensel's lemma. (English)

### Exposition. Math. 3 (1985), no. 1, 3--24.

I have been unable to find the paper mentioned. Can someone help me obtain a digital copy of this paper? Please let me know, and apologies if this isn't the right forum to pose this question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be included in this book, but it's £99;

https://www.bookdepository.com/Collected-Works-Ordered-Structures-Mathematical-Logic-Paulo-Ribenboim/9783319721439

There's a chapter here that looks promising by Franz-Viktor Kuhlmann;
https://math.usask.ca/~fvk/bookch9.pdf

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I've been looking for a digital copy, as I don't think it will be possible to get this book my present situation. I've looked at the second link.

Comment: Yes, that's a silly price... Nothing obvious from a quick google search. Good luck finding it !

Comment: The price is a bit much, but I'm worried about shipping charges too :) Thanks for the links and help!

Comment: It might help to add the tag p-adic numbers to your question

Comment: Maybe you missed it, but I already posted that review 25 years ago in the linked post in the question, as well as in an [answer here 5 years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/709564/242).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque : Ah, apologies, no point having the duplication; I've removed it.