# Solving polynomial congruences like $2x^2+7x+1\equiv 0\pmod{\!8}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

We were asked to solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}_8$: $[2]x^2+[7]x+[1]=0.\,$ I know how to do this by brute-force checking all eight possible residues $\!\bmod 8,\,$ but is there a better way? (I mean, using ring properties or something like that). Because if the problem involved a much larger modulus then brute force checking would be hopelessly ineffieicnt.

Comment: Even $\pmod {56}$, trial and error is very rapid.  You can simplify your life by factoring your modulus and using [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) for primes.  Note that extracting square roots modulo composite numbers is equivalent to factoring, which makes this quite a hard problem in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *general* method: lift (easy) roots $\!\bmod 2\,$ to $\!\bmod 2^3$ by  [Hensel's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3545926/242) (Newton's method). Here we have  $\,f(x)\equiv 2x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1\pmod{\!8}\,$ so

$\!\!\bmod 2\!:\,\ 0\equiv f(x)\equiv 2x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1\equiv -x\!+\!1$ $\iff x\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{x = 1\!+\!2y}$

$\!\!\bmod 8\!:\,\ 0 \equiv f(\color{#c00}x)\equiv 2(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!2y})^2\!-\!(\color{#c00}{1\!+\!2y})\!+\!1\equiv -2y\!+\!2$ $\overset{\div\ 2}\iff \bmod 4\!:\ 0\equiv -y\!+\!1$
$\iff y = 1\!+\!4n\iff x = 1\!+\!2y = 3\!+\!8n\equiv 3\pmod{\!8}$

Comment: We implicitly used $\, y\equiv a\pmod{\!4}\!\iff\! 2y\equiv 2a\pmod{\!8},\,$ by $\,4\mid y-a\!\iff\! 8\mid 2(y-a).\,$ More generally see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883921/242) for scaling and cancellation of congruences.

Answer (score -2):

First observe that in $Z_8$, $7 = - 9, 1 = 9$. This allows you to factor it as $(2x-3)(x-3) = 0$. Thus $x - 3 = 0 \implies x = 3$ or $2x - 3 = 0$ which yields no solution in $Z_8$. All the other possibilities are ruled out. For example: $x-3 = 2, 2x-3 = 4$ simmulatneously leads to no solution. Thus the only answer is $x = 3$.

Comment: Guessing the correct factors is almost the same as  guessing the correct zeroes. This is not a method that can be used for a larger modulus.

Comment: Easier: $\,2x\!-\!3\,$ is odd so coprime to $8,\,$ so $\,8\mid (2x\!-\!3)(x\!-\!3)\,\Rightarrow\,  8\mid x-3\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.